# Is the tensor product of 2 finite extension of $\Bbb Q$ isomorphic to a direct sum of fields?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I have $K_1$ and $K_2$ two finite extensions of $\Bbb Q$. I can construct $K_1 \otimes_\Bbb Q K_2$.

This is clearly isomorphic to a direct sum of field as vector space (indeed one can easily see that it is isomorphic to a direct sum of $n_1 \times n_2$ copies of $\Bbb Q$ where $n_i$ is the finite dimension of $K_i$ over $\Bbb Q$ simply by writing a base of $K_1 \otimes_\Bbb Q K_2$ from the bases of $K_1$ and $K_2$).

Now I would like to know if this is still true as rings. i.e. is there a ring isomorphism from the ring $K_1 \otimes_\Bbb Q K_2$ to a direct sum of field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Using the primitive element theorem, you can write $K_1 = \mathbb{Q}[x]/f(x)$ for some irreducible polynomial $f$. Then

$$K_1 \otimes K_2 \cong K_2[x]/f(x).$$

Since $K_2$ is separable, so is the polynomial $f(x)$, so we get a product of fields corresponding to the irreducible factors of $f(x)$ over $K_2$.

This is not true if $\mathbb{Q}$ is replaced by a field which is not perfect. For example, if $k = \mathbb{F}_p(a)$ and $K_1 = K_2 = k[x]/(x^p - a)$, then

$$K_1 \otimes K_2 \cong K_1[x]/(x^p - a) \cong K_1[x]/(x - \sqrt[p]{a})^p$$

is not reduced. In this case it's necessary to assume additionally that $K_1$ and $K_2$ are separable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer !
how do you know that $L \otimes L \cong \prod_{g \in G} L.$ ? Is this a classic Galois theory result ?

Comment: @Thalanza: yes, in some sense. You can prove it in this setting by using the primitive element theorem. Although upon reflection, you might as well use that to prove the original result. I'll edit.

Comment: @ QiaochuYuan : Ok, it is much clearer now. Still, I don't understand how the separability of $f$ gives us a direct sum of the irreducible factors of$f(x)$ over $K_2$. Isn't $f$ already an ireducible polynomial ?

Comment: I think, @QiaochuYuan, that something is wrong, since $K_1=\Bbb F_p[x]/(x^p-a)$ is not a field. Namely, every $a\in\Bbb F_p$ has a $p$-th root, itself in this case. I think you needed a nonperfect field for a base rather than $\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: And, @Thalanza, $f$ is to be irreducible over the base $k$, but may not be over $K_2$. I think that the example $K_1=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]5)$ and $K_2=\Bbb Q(\omega\sqrt[3]5)$, where $\omega$ is a primitive cube root of unity, should be eminently computable, and you can see what happens. In fact, maybe clearer to take $K_2=K_1$ here.

Comment: Ok, I see now that $f$ is not irreducible over $K_2$, thanks for that.

I have done all the detail from the start and everything is quite clear now but I am still in trouble with the conclusion. How can we conclude that a ring of polynomial quotiented by the ideal of a reducible function (namely $K_2[X]/(f)$) is a direct sum of field. It might be some basic stuff that I miss. Thank a lot for all the help so far !